# How to speedup this vectorized numpy-function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numba

I've been using
`@Divakars` function 'justify_nd' the last days and it works very well. Its very efficient when ran on **large** datasets.
I now have another problem:

The function sometimes also has to be called very often on smaller splits (millions of times).
Therefore I thought of adding a `@jit` decorator it via numba. unfortunately `numba` doesnt support `np.moveaxis()`.

So: is there a way to do this with `np.transpose()`?

### @Divakars function:

```
def justify_nd(a, invalid_val, axis, side):    
    """
    Justify ndarray for the valid elements (that are not invalid_val).

    Parameters
    ----------
    A : ndarray
        Input array to be justified
    invalid_val : scalar
        invalid value
    axis : int
        Axis along which justification is to be made
    side : str
        Direction of justification. Must be 'front' or 'end'.
        So, with 'front', valid elements are pushed to the front and
        with 'end' valid elements are pushed to the end along specified axis.
    """
    
    pushax = lambda a: np.moveaxis(a, axis, -1)
    if invalid_val is np.nan:
        mask = ~np.isnan(a)
    else:
        mask = a!=invalid_val
    justified_mask = np.sort(mask,axis=axis)
    
    if side=='front':
        justified_mask = np.flip(justified_mask,axis=axis)
            
    out = np.full(a.shape, invalid_val)
    if (axis==-1) or (axis==a.ndim-1):
        out[justified_mask] = a[mask]
    else:
        pushax(out)[pushax(justified_mask)] = pushax(a)[pushax(mask)]
    return out
```

### minimal reproducable sample:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, random
len_ = 6; drop_Beginning_LEN = 3  ;np.random.seed(777); seed_2 = 5

for i in range(1000):# just calling it 1000 times

   ''' generating sample data '''
   
   a = pd.DataFrame({  "A":np.random.uniform(low=0.0005, high=13.12333, size=(len_)),  "B":np.random.uniform(low=0.0005, high=133.12333,       size=(len_)), "C": np.random.uniform(low=0.0001, high=13.12333, size=(len_)), "D":np.random.uniform(low=0.000005,    high=633242.12333,     size=(len_))}, dtype=np.float64)
   for col in a.columns: # place nans randomly
       a[col].iloc[random.sample(range(0, len_-1), int(len_*0.3))] = np.nan; random.seed(seed_2 ); seed_2+=1
  
   nans = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(len(a)), columns=a.columns))
   nans = list((map(lambda i: nans[:i], range(0,nans.shape[0]))))
   nans    = nans[::-1] # turning it around
   a = np.asarray(a) 
   a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1, a.shape[0]+1))))
   a = np.asarray([np.concatenate((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,nans)])   
   a = np.asarray(a[(drop_Beginning_LEN-1):])

   ''' function '''
   a = justify_generic(a, invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side="end")
   #print(a)
```

### expected outcome:

(when called with `len_ = 6; drop_Beginning_LEN =3 ;np.random.seed(777)`)

```
''' 
as we see: the nans are pushed to the top, but the order of the valid values remains.
[[[           nan            nan            nan            nan]
  [           nan            nan            nan            nan]
  [2.00388024e+00 9.67793310e+01 7.73773690e+00 1.70253514e+05]
  [3.96827439e+00 1.02304892e+02 4.50583685e+00 2.36363566e+05]
  [8.14593324e-01 3.58378403e+01 1.29773491e+01 1.41167463e+05]
  [6.03516909e+00 8.57355020e+01 8.22145197e+00 1.18063308e+05]]

 [[           nan            nan            nan            nan]
  [2.00388024e+00 9.67793310e+01 7.73773690e+00 1.70253514e+05]
  [3.96827439e+00 1.02304892e+02 4.50583685e+00 2.36363566e+05]
  [8.14593324e-01 3.58378403e+01 1.29773491e+01 1.41167463e+05]
  [6.03516909e+00 8.57355020e+01 8.22145197e+00 1.18063308e+05]
  [1.09613882e+01 1.24306122e+01 8.94724630e+00 2.47374828e+05]]

 [[2.00388024e+00 9.67793310e+01 7.73773690e+00 1.70253514e+05]
  [3.96827439e+00 1.02304892e+02 4.50583685e+00 2.36363566e+05]
  [8.14593324e-01 3.58378403e+01 1.29773491e+01 1.41167463e+05]
  [6.03516909e+00 8.57355020e+01 8.22145197e+00 1.18063308e+05]
  [1.09613882e+01 1.24306122e+01 8.94724630e+00 2.47374828e+05]
  [1.21653247e+01 1.06085106e+01 7.24749319e+00 1.22318572e+05]]]
```

### Important:

I only need the parametersets `invalid_val=np.nan, axis=1, side="end")`

Edit: I forgot to place random nans in the dataframe.-> Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With a 3d array, these are equivalent:

```
In [13]: a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [14]: np.moveaxis(a, 1, -1).shape
Out[14]: (2, 4, 3)
In [16]: np.transpose(a, [0,2,1]).shape
```

It appears that if you did this transpose before hand, so the shoving is done on the last axis rather than the middle, the function could be written without `pushax` (since `axis==-1`).

Comment: I just noticed, that I forgot to randomly place np.nan values in the `a` dataframe. Will this affect the result?

Comment: Tried it -> unfortunately the submatrices are mirrored vertically (from left to right) :(